# How to retrieve only last 4 characters in a string using XPath Query

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using xpaths to retrieve various data points out of an XML formatted file.

There is a situation where I only want to extract the last 4 digits of a value, but I cannot figure out how.

I've tested various substring methods found on this site, but none work.

```xml
<TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIERS>
     <TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIER SequenceNumber="1">
         <TaxpayerIdentifierType>SocialSecurityNumber</TaxpayerIdentifierType>
         <TaxpayerIdentifierValue>123456789</TaxpayerIdentifierValue>
     </TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIER>
</TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIERS>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is a situation where I only want to extract the last 4 digits of a value, but I cannot figure out how.

To retrieve the last 4 digits of a value, e.g. `TaxpayerIdentifierValue`, you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
substring(/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIERS/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIER/TaxpayerIdentifierValue, string-length(/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIERS/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIER/TaxpayerIdentifierValue) - 4 + 1, 4)
```

Its output is:

> 6789

Answer (score 0):

If the current node is the TaxpayerIdentifierValue, just call `substring` and use `string-length` to calculate the starting position of the substring:

```
substring(., string-length(.) - 3)
```

Which, starting from the root, makes it

```
substring(/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIERS/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIER/TaxpayerIdentifierValue,
          string-length(/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIERS/TAXPAYER_IDENTIFIER/TaxpayerIdentifierValue) - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple xpath.

```
//TaxpayerIdentifierValue/substring(., string-length(.) - 3)
```

**Here is the output screenshot:**
[image]

You can also use the below xpath.

```
//TaxpayerIdentifierValue/substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 3)
```

[image]